# Finding an element in a cyclic group of prime order

Tags: java, algorithm, math, cyclic

How do I check if an element a belongs to a specific cyclic group G of prime order, given the generator? Right now i simply generate all the elements in the group, save them into a container and check if the element is in it. This is the code im currently using to generate all the elements of the group:

```
public HashSet<BigInteger> group_elements(BigInteger g, BigInteger q) {

    HashSet<BigInteger> group = new HashSet<BigInteger>();

    BigInteger element = modPow(g,ONE,q);

    for (int i = 2; !group.contains(element); i++) {
        group.add(element);
        element = modPow(g, BigInteger.valueOf(i), q);
    }

    return group;

}
```

And to see if a element is in the group i simply check:

```
if (group.contains(num)) { ... }
```

As you can see the language is Java

Comment: Which language are you using and **show us what you have tried**

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't just write out code, but your programming seems fine.  It's the math of the problem which held you up, I think.

Comment: Wait, what? Your group is the multiplicative group of order q, right? So *any* integer not divisible by q is an element of the group. [Or, if you're picking a representative for each residue class, as your code does, then the group is just {1, ... , q-1}.] Either way, you don't have to write so much code. :-)

Comment: I assume that the questioner actually meant that G is the subgroup of (Z/q)* generated by g.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because I think I was wrong about what kind of group you're thinking of.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have some more information about what the group looks like.

If you know the order of the group G generated by g, and if q is prime (you only told us that the order of G is prime, but nothing about q) then you can check if an element x is in G by testing

> 1 = x<sup>ord(G)</sup> mod q.

If q is not prime then this test does not work. A counter example, would be g = 22, q = 91, x = 53. Here g generates the subgroup with the elements {1, 22, 29}. x also has order 3, but is not an element of the subgroup generated by g.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem and the [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms) for solving it.